# Add custom block on each application page

Tags: visualforce, pageblock

I noticed that almost ALL pages in my application have "Recent Items" block

[image]

Can I somehow create such "custom blocks" and add them to each page, for example under "Recent Items"?

Comment: In order to achieve something like this you would need to create a custom Visual Force Page for each of your objects and link the display tab for your objects to your vf page. It requires quite a deal of coding so it's not advisable to do it unless you have some experience with it.

Comment: Marc, does salesforce have like master layout where I could insert some content to be visible an all pages?

Comment: Not completely sure but from my understanding, each object has a standard vf page layout which you are unable to modify or edit. So the only solution would be to create a custom one.

Comment: Search for homepage components..

Comment: See Home Page Component   https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=home_page_components_custom_create.htm&language=en_US

Comment: I updated home page layout with HTML Area, and it appeared on my Home page, but unfortunately all other pages (Accounts, Leads, etc) were not affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out how to do that.

1. First of all - you should create "Home Page Component"
2. Add component to Home Page
3. And significant step: Setup > Customize > User
   Interface.  Check the box next to Show Custom Sidebar Components on
   All Pages.